# How to add a custom class to a div in fotorama plugin?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a gallery made with Fotorama plugin. What I need and I don't know how to do is to add a custom class to a specific div, the properties doesn't matter, I need to know how to hook that class to existing code. That class I want to add to 2nd div that wraps every thumbnail image(the one with tabindex="0").
Fotorama has a hard to understand codeing style(atleast for me).

```
  <div class="fotorama__nav__frame fotorama__nav__frame--thumb" tabindex="0" role="button" style="width: 64pxl">
       <div class="fotorama__thumb fotorama__loaded fotorama__loaded--img">
         <img src="imagini/stilllife.jpg" class="fotorama__img" style="width: 64px; height: 85px; left: 0px; top: -11px;">
       </div>
</div>
```

Any advice is highly welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the your custom class with following snippet (check the HTML and then inspect the HTML after running the snippet), as you said this fotorama class is applied to every thumbnail, so you can add your custom class to every thumbnail frame element which has --> `fotorama__nav__frame--thumb` class

**EDITED**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fotorama__nav__frame--thumb").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('yourClass');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fotorama__nav__frame fotorama__nav__frame--thumb" tabindex="0" role="button" style="width: 64pxl">
  <div class="fotorama__thumb fotorama__loaded fotorama__loaded--img">
    <img src="http://awesomeshit.ninja/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/grumpy-cat-no.jpg" class="fotorama__img" style="width: 64px; height: 85px; left: 0px; top: -11px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, sry, forgot to add a for-each loop. Now it should apply to every div with class `fotorama__nav__frame--thumb`